# Reset index in pandas dataframe improve AUC of predictive model

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

My goal is to find predictive model to determine whether a loan will be repaid or not. My source is a CSV file with caracteristics of loans and whether they have been repaid or not. 
I assess the performance of my model using ROC curve and AUC

```
df = pd.read_csv(your_path)
X = df.values 
y = df.defaults
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test  = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, 
random_state=7)
log_reg = LogisticRegression()
log_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_score)
print(auc(fpr,tpr))
```

When I compute this code, I got an AUC score of around 0.75.

But when I add the command line 'df = df.reset_index()' as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(your_path)
df = df.reset_index()
X = df.values 
y = df.defaults
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test  = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, 
random_state=7)
log_reg = LogisticRegression()
log_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_score)
print(auc(fpr,tpr))
```

I got an AUC of 0.93. It just increased for no apparent reason.

Why does the fact of resetting the index increase my model AUC ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

resetting the index the way you did it adds the index as a column. This column can then be used in your classifier as an input feature. Your index can then influence the accuracy of your prediction.

consider this example df:

```
         class  max_speed
falcon    bird      389.0
parrot    bird       24.0
lion    mammal       80.5
monkey  mammal        NaN
```

if we do this

```
df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
```

the resulting dataframe looks like this.

```
    index   class   max_speed
0   falcon  bird    389.0
1   parrot  bird    24.0
2   lion    mammal  80.5
3   monkey  mammal  NaN
```

To prevent this from happening you can do this:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop = True)
df
```

resulting in this dataframe:

```
    class   max_speed
0   bird    389.0
1   bird    24.0
2   mammal  80.5
3   mammal  NaN
```

This way the previous index is not added as a column to your dataframe.

Edit:
Additionally you can set the `random_state` argument in your `LogisticRegression()` to be sure there are no random effects in the accuracy of your regressor.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot !